# Sending differing emails to addresses

Tags: python, windows, api, email, pywin32

I am trying to automate an emailing process at work and got everything working down to the final line.

Here is the issue confined to its own test script to ensure the error is not something else:

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.application")
addresses = ["email1", "email2"]

for address in addresses:
    email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    email.To = address
    email.Subject = "Attendance"
    email.Body = " - "
    email.send()
```

The email will send to the first email address if valid, but not the second.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jbruce\OneDrive - Stirling Skills Training\Reporting\EST\Auto attendance\Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    email.send()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

I am mainly puzzled about why the script will run one step of the for loop, but not the other.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: can you share the entire traceback?

Comment: Without digging in, a thought: Have you look at `CreateItem()`? That may be where your `Bool` is coming from. Try `CreateItem()`, without the `0`.

Comment: CreateItem() parameter's are not optional however.

Comment: @Kindapink Never mind. I dug in a little. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
email.Send()
```

The issue here is that:

```
email.send
```

is, in fact, a `Bool`.